# print "more to follow" for repeating frame at bottom of page in Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, report

using Oracle 10g reports builder.

I have a report layout with a repeating frame with many entries in the middle f the layout. (ie objects before and after)

what i want is for when the frame wraps to the next page i want to put a "More Record to Follow" message.

is that possible?

the frame is variable sized.. so i cant count rows either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you're after is the **Print Object On** setting.

Create the boilerplate text "More Record to Follow" inside your repeating frame, go to its properties, and set Print Object On to **All But Last Page**.

Comment: nope.. that doesn't work..  its just does not print at all..

which is because each instance of the repeating frame is only on '1 page' and so the current page is _always_ the 'last page' for the frame instance.